# Java collections -- polymorphic access to elements

Tags: java, collections, polymorphism

I have a **LinkedHashSet** of values of **ThisType**. 
**ThisType** is implementing the interface **ThatType**.

I need the polymorphic use of this collection-- be able to point to it as **LinkedHashSet< ThatType >.**

How is this done?

i know this is a naive question, but several things i tried didn't work, and i wanna do it the right way.

Thanks in advance.

//==============================

UPDATE: more details:

In the following code, **ThisType** implements **ThatType**-- **ThatType** is an interface.

```
//LinkedHashMap<Integer, ? extends ThatType> theMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
LinkedHashMap<Integer, ThisType> theMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (Integer key:intArray)  {
    ThisType a = new ThisType();
    if (theMap.containsKey(key))  {
        a = theMap.get(key);    
        a.doStuff();
    } else {
        a.doOtherStuff();
    }
    theMap.put(key, a);
}
```

In the end, i wanna return the **theMap** as a collection of **ThatType **, not **ThisType**.

this is where the chain is broken. using the commented line (first line) for declaration is giving type mismatch error on **put()** & **get()** methods of the hash.

not sure whether this is significant-- but, 
i'm returning the result as **LinkedHashSet< ThatType >**. i'm doing the conversion from **LinkedHashMap** to **LinkedHashSet**. However, nothing worked nowhere for the polymorphic reference to collection values in the map or set. All and only type i used in all these operations so far is **ThisType**. **ThatType** gave me some error just about anywhere i tried it.

Comment: What exactly do you need to do?

Comment: i'll pass it as a param

Comment: I read it thrice, and still couldn't comprehend what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*polymorphic use*"?

Comment: or rather, return it as LinkedHashSet<ThatType> while it's all LinkedHashSet<ThisType> everywhere inside.

Comment: this isn't diong it -- i'll rephrase & ask. will use a code segment.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is to use wildcards.

```
 LinkedHashSet<? extends ThatType> someFunction(LinkedHashSet<? extends ThatType> set) {
      return set;
 }
```

As has been explained elsewhere `LinkedHashSet<ThisType>` is not a subclass of `LinkedHashSet<ThatType>`, since `LinkedHashSet<ThisType>` can't accept `ThatType` objects.

The wildcard in `LinkedHashSet<? extends ThatType>` means a `LinkedHastSet` of some class (not sure what) that extends `ThatType`.

Though you may want to consider using this:

```
 Set<? extends ThatType> someFunction(Set<? extends ThatType> set) {
      return set;
 }
```

Comment: it's the other way round-- misphraesd the Q. but i'll try this.

Comment: i wanna preserve the order of elements-- gotta be the linked list

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a wildcard bounded type argument as in

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, ? extends ThatType> theMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

you are telling the compiler that the type argument can be any class that is a sub type of `ThatType`. Imagine this case

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, ? extends ThatType> theMap = getLinkedHashMap();
```

where `getLinkedHashMap()` is defined as

```
public LinkedHashMap<Integer, OtherType /* which implements ThatType */> getLinkedHashMap();
```

The previous assignment would work because `OtherType` is a sub type of `ThatType`. However, you could not then expect

```
ThisType a = theMap.get(key);
```

to work. Because of the wildcard, all you know is that the map definitely contains  `ThatType` instances (called the **upper bound**), but they could be of type `OtherType` or `ThatType` (or other sub type of `ThatType`). At most you could do

```
ThisType a = (ThisType) theMap.get(key);
```

casting the return value, but then you are opening yourself up to `ClassCastException`.

Similarly, you cannot call `put()` with anything other than than `null`.

```
theMap.put(someInt, null); // will compile
theMap.put(someInt, new ThisType()); // will not compile
theMap.put(someInt, new OtherType()); // will not compile
```

The compiler doesn't let you add anything because it can't guarantee what the map contains, again because of the wildcard bound. But [`null` can be used because](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1)

> The null reference can always undergo a widening reference conversion
>   to any reference type.

So `null` is a valid argument because it is [the **lower bound** of the wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10).

---

You're in a special situation where, it seems, your method creates the `LinkedHashMap` internally and you know what you will be passing to it. Therefore you can do the following

```
public static LinkedHashMap<Integer, ThatType> getTheSet(int[] intArray) {
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, ThatType> theMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (Integer key : intArray) {
        ThisType a = new ThisType();
        if (theMap.containsKey(key)) {
            a = (ThisType) theMap.get(key); // cast it because you know they will definitely be `ThisType` references
            a.doStuff();
        } else {
            a.doOtherStuff();
        }
        theMap.put(key, a);
    }

    return theMap;
}
```

Since `ThisType` is a sub type of `ThatType`, you can put instances of `ThisType` into the map. You need to be careful how you then use this method's returned value. All the compiler knows about the return value is that it contains `ThatType` references. It doesn't know that they are actually `ThisType`.

Answer (score 0):

You need the wildcard of `Set<? super ThisType>`. Look at following example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<ThatType> set=new LinkedHashSet<>();
    Set<ThisType> set2=new LinkedHashSet<>();

    someFunction(set);
    someFunction(set2);
}

static void someFunction(Set<? super ThisType> set) {

}

class ThisType implements ThatType{

}
interface ThatType{

}
```