# Can Java generics only be extended ONLY on parameter passing?

Tags: java, generics

I asked this Q in another form in [Java collections -- polymorphic access to elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946238/java-collections-polymorphic-access-to-elements--) couldn't get an answer.

I can build a collection of **ThisType** in one method and 
pass it as param to another method using generic **.** 
But there must be a better way to do this(?)

**ThisType** here is implementing **ThatType** where **ThatType** is an interface.

Comment: Flag that question for moderator attention. Posting a duplicate question is not going to solve your purpose. Or start a bounty on your question.

Comment: Also it seems like you are in a hurry to get the answer as you have asked the question today itself. Give it time.

Answer (score 0):

So declare your collection as `Collection<ThatType>` and return that. Since ThisType implements ThatType, you've solved your problem.

Comment: that doesnt work. see that flagged Q.